# Updating View in success callback of Model.destroy()

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

Actually I am developing an application in backbone marionette framework. I have an simple query I searched a lot but not able to understand how to make it working. The problem is with `Model.destroy()`.  What I want is when I am calling `Model.destroy()` first the entry has to get from server and if the response is positive then in success Call back the view should be removed.

This is my code

```
model.destroy({
    success: function (model, response) {

    },
    error: function (model, response) {

    }
});
```

But what is happening now weather it is deleted ornot from the server i.e. Which ever callback is called it will be removed from screen. So I want to remove te model from view if it goes to success callback.

Please advice.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally your model really shouldn't need to know anything about its views. Instead what you should be doing is binding your view to listen to events on your model.

If you need to wait for your server to send back a response that the model has been destroyed you can pass in the`{wait: true}` option when calling the destroy method.

For example, in your view's [initialize](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) method you can bind it to listen to your models [destroy](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy) event,

```
 initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, "destroy", this.destroy);
 }
```

Comment: that is fine I will wait but how can I force it to remove only in success call back.

Comment: I don't think the `remove` event will fire if the error callback fires so by default it should only remove it when the success call back has fired. However if you would like you can fire some other event on your model in your success callback and listen to that event in your view instead of the `destroy` event.